# Cannot install RUBY Gem Twitter on MAC OS

Tags: ruby, macos, twitter, makefile, rubygems

I have a problem trying to install the gem twitter on MAC OS.

I input the command `sudo gem install twitter`

and got the following result :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing twitter:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
/Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170712-36084-peffuw.rb extconf.rb

creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean
/usr/local/bin/make:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

current directory: /Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
/usr/local/bin/make:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Will/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
```

I already tried stuff from around the net (installed XCode command line tools, re-installed Ruby and rvm...) and I'm all out of ideas/solutions/places to search...

Could you please help me ?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Did you try to install http_parser first?

Comment: Also, you should verify if you have accepted xcode condition. It can produce some strange behavior if not but I don't know if you're problem is related to that.

Comment: @VitalyFry Yes I tried same error appeared, there seemed to have a problem with my `make` command

Comment: I finally found what went wrong with the help of a friend : the ruby gem exec `make` replaced the original `make` from xcode command line tools because I forced the installation of gems via sudo command.</br>I had to remove the gem make in my  `/usr/local/bin/make` folder</br>Anyhow, thanks guys for the help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like make is trying to load things from the default ruby: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make (LoadError)` rather than from your rvm-installed ruby. I'd try installing the make gem with `gem install make` to see if that resolves your issue.

You could also check your GEM_PATH environment variable to make sure that local gems aren't being used before the gems installed for your rvm ruby.